# How to connect my server to my app

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am using hostinger.web.tr. And I want to upload small data. They are a username, email, and password. When I click the button; my emulator gives me registered toast message. But when I check my PHPMyAdmin panel; there is no something there. How can I connect my server to my app?

My php folder :

```
<?php

        define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
        define('USER','******');
        define('PASS','******');
    define('DB','******');
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
        $username = $_GET['username'];

    $password = $_GET['password'];

    $email = $_GET['email'];
        if($username == '' || $password == '' || $email == '')
        {

        echo 'please fill all values';
        }
        else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";
            $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
        if(isset($check)){
        echo 'username or email already exist';
        }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO signup (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'successfully registered';

    }
        else{

            echo 'oops! Please try again!';

        }
}

            mysqli_close($con);
        }   ?>
```

My android activity :

```
    giris_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            registir();



        }

        private void registir() {
            String user_name_string = kullanıcı_edittext.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String password_string  = sifre_edittext.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String emai = sonra_sil_edittext.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

            register_information(user_name_string, emai, password_string);
        }


    });
}

private void register_information(String user_name_string, String emai, String password_string) {

    String urlSuffix = "?username=" + user_name_string + "&password=" + emai + "&email=" + password_string;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(giris_ekrani.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader=null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result=bufferReader.readLine();
                return  result;

            }catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
    RegisterUser ur=new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlSuffix);




}
```

My logcat :

```
04-18 03:20:40.305 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.314 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.321 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.331 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.340 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.345 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.351 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.357 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.368 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.372 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.385 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.709 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.727 1587-2071/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@fd8c4a6 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@fabdf40
04-18 03:20:40.741 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.767 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:40.900 1587-1607/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Please Wait) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:491 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
04-18 03:20:41.234 5465-5486/something.about.berkay.isim D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb9dfe0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb96920)
04-18 03:20:43.283 1587-1607/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Toast) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
04-18 03:20:43.492 1347-1369/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2024872 , only wrote 1872000
```

Comment: what message it is giving

Comment: I take only Registered message in my toast. By the way I am so beginner. I just want to register my datas to server ( with username , password , email )

Comment: I edited my question with logcat.

Comment: inside `onPostExecute`, log the value of `s` and check what it says

Comment: giris_ekrani: onPostExecute: null